# How can I break a regex into multiple lines?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've built a custom validator in my rails app which makes sure that an address is formatted as follows:

> Recipient Name:
>
> Address Line 1:
>
> Address Line 2:
>
> City:
>
> State:
>
> ZIP Code:

--OR--

> Bank Account Number:
>
> Bank Routing Number:
>
> Bank Account Type:

I've implemented the following helper methods to check if an address doesn't match one of these patterns:

```
def malformed_check(address)
  address !~ /^Recipient Name:(.*)$\n^Address Line 1:(.*)$\n(^Address Line 2:(.*)$\n)?^City:(.*)$\n^State:(.*)$\n^ZIP Code:(.*)$/
end

def malformed_ach(address)
  address !~ /^Bank Account Number:(.*)$\n^Bank Routing Number:(.*)$\n^Bank Account Type:(.*)$/
end
```

My question is: how can I break my regexes across multiple lines?

We have a 120 char max per line in our coding standard.

Comment: Why are you capturing `(.*)`? That is unnecessary unless you're going to do something with the captured text. Also, the intermediate `$` and following `^` are unnecessary if you have the embedded `\n`. You can do line-end/line-begin anchors, or `\n` but don't need both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/x` freespace modifier allows you to have regex on multiple lines, e.g.

```
address !~ /^Recipient Name:(.*)$\n
            ^Address Line 1:(.*)$\n
           (^Address Line 2:(.*)$\n)?
            ^City:(.*)$\n
            ^State:(.*)$\n
            ^ZIP Code:(.*)$/x
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope "[Free-Spacing Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html)" can help you!

For Ruby specifically, check the [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html) documentation, which says:

> The end delimiter for a regexp can be followed by one or more single-letter options which control how the pattern can match.

```
/pat/i - Ignore case
/pat/m - Treat a newline as a character matched by .
/pat/x - Ignore whitespace and comments in the pattern
/pat/o - Perform #{} interpolation only once
```

> ...the x option enables free-spacing mode. Literal white space inside the pattern is ignored, and the octothorpe (#) character introduces a comment until the end of the line. This allows the components of the pattern to be organised in a potentially more readable fashion.
>
> Note: To match whitespace in an x pattern use an escape such as \s or \p{Space}.